# HTML5 Canvas, Button instead of Keyboard

Tags: html, canvas

Found some nice Open Source code of a snake game, but wanting to make an iphone web version. So I can't use a physical keyboard, is it possible to use a button instead of it?

Have this code:

```
case 37:
  if (direction != "right"){
    moveLeft();
  }
  break;
```

Got some more questions but this one is the one 's keeping me where I am in the dev.

Sorry for my bad English, I am a dutch guy.

thanks

Comment: You could use accelerometer too :)

Comment: @thomas, that would be the nicest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Canvas for this, just create a regular HTML button and put that code in its onclick event.